# How to use two different analyze-strings for one node

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

In my XSLT transformation I have two analyze-strings that I need to use to process one node. They work fine one by one, but I don't know how to put them together.

XML document looks like this:

```
<article>
    <title>Article 1</title>
    <text><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, s consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem diam, eleifend sed mollis id, condimentum in velit.

Sed sit amet erat ac mauris adipiscing elementum. Pellentesque eget quam augue, id faucibus magna.

Ut malesuada arcu eu elit sodales sodales. Morbi tristique porttitor tristique. Praesent eget vulputate dui. Cras ut tortor massa, at faucibus ligula.]]></text>
</article>
```

Here's my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>Page title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="article">
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="./title"/></h1>

                <!-- This adds paragraphs tags instead of empty lines in the text -->
                <xsl:analyze-string select="./text" regex="&#xa;">
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        </p>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string> 

                <!-- This is Czech language specific. It looks for ' s ' (or other letter) and changes second space for &nbsp;. So after that it is ' s&nbsp;'. -->
                <xsl:analyze-string select="./text" regex="(\s[k/K/s/S/v/V/z/Z]\s)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' ','')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to apply both analyze-strings on the generated text so there are `<p>` tags for paragraphs and also added `&nbsp;` on the right places.

My desired output would look like this:

```
<h1>Article 1</h1>    
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, s&nbsp;consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem diam, eleifend sed mollis id, condimentum in velit.</p>
<p>Sed sit amet erat ac mauris adipiscing elementum. Pellentesque eget quam augue, id faucibus magna.</p>
<p>Ut malesuada arcu eu elit sodales sodales. Morbi tristique porttitor tristique. Praesent eget vulputate dui. Cras ut tortor massa, at faucibus ligula.</p>
```

Any idea how to do this? Thank you for taking your time and trying to help me.

Comment: You forgot to provide the source XML document. Please, edit the question and provide this.

Comment: Clarifications sought. Please see the notes section in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my tweak on Dimitre's solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/text">
   <xsl:for-each select="tokenize( replace(., '\s([kKsSvVzZ])\s', ' $1&#xA0;'), '\n')">
     <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Notes**

1. I am not sure what you mean by "the letters s/S/v/V/k/K/z/Z". This is not valid regex. You need to clarify. I have taken a guess that you meant the character class [sSvVkKzZ]
2. Although not clear, the reference to the Czech language suggests that UTF-8 might be a better choice for output encoding rather than ASCII.
3. Although not clear, the expected output tags, suggest a more appropriate serialization would be html.
4. As a side benefit of choosing html serialization, we no longer need the character map, making our solution simpler. We can leverage the in-built character map for html serialization.
5. Use of fn:tokenise() obviates the need for xsl:analyze-string/xsl:non-matching-substring nodes, arguably resulting in a tighter solution.
6. This solution was tested with Saxon.
7. Variations are possible. For example you could move the replace() invocation to inside the xsl:value-of, which you may regard as more read-able.
8. The disadvantage of my solution is that it does not work with disable-output-escaping="yes" . However I suggest that if you think you need this, please look again strongly at why. Any HTML needs HTML-safe encoding unless it is inside a CDATA section. There is something not right with the idea of generating HTML with disable-output-escaping turned on. Perhaps I have not fully understood the question. Could you give a Use Case which clarifies the point?

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="ascii"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/text">
  <xsl:analyze-string select=
   "replace(., '\ss\s', ' s&#xA0;')"
   regex="&#xA;">
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <p><xsl:sequence select="."/></p>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<article>
  <title>Article 1</title>
<text><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, s consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem diam, eleifend sed mollis id, condimentum in velit.
Sed sit amet erat ac mauris adipiscing elementum. Pellentesque eget quam augue, id faucibus magna.
Ut malesuada arcu eu elit sodales sodales. Morbi tristique porttitor tristique. Praesent eget vulputate dui. Cras ut tortor massa, at faucibus ligula.]]></text>
</article>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
  <h1>Article 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, s&#160;consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem diam, eleifend sed mollis id, condimentum in velit.</p>
<p>Sed sit amet erat ac mauris adipiscing elementum. Pellentesque eget quam augue, id faucibus magna.</p>
<p>Ut malesuada arcu eu elit sodales sodales. Morbi tristique porttitor tristique. Praesent eget vulputate dui. Cras ut tortor massa, at faucibus ligula.</p>
```

**Note**: Programmers are discouraged to use DOE, as it is not a mandatory feature of XSLT 2.0 and there are no guarantees that any XSLT 2.0 processor might support DOE. The feature to use instead, is **[character maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#character-maps)**.

**Then the whole transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
  encoding="ascii" use-character-maps="nbsp"/>

 <xsl:character-map name="nbsp">
  <xsl:output-character
  character="&#xA0;" string="&amp;nbsp;"/>
 </xsl:character-map>

 <xsl:template match="/*/text">
  <xsl:analyze-string select=
   "replace(., '\ss\s', ' s&#xA0;')"
   regex="&#xA;">
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <p><xsl:sequence select="."/></p>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the same XML document (above), it produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
  <h1>Article 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, s&nbsp;consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem diam, eleifend sed mollis id, condimentum in velit.</p>
<p>Sed sit amet erat ac mauris adipiscing elementum. Pellentesque eget quam augue, id faucibus magna.</p>
<p>Ut malesuada arcu eu elit sodales sodales. Morbi tristique porttitor tristique. Praesent eget vulputate dui. Cras ut tortor massa, at faucibus ligula.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre, I have two more questions.

I need to add nbsp; after all of the letters s/S/v/V/k/K/z/Z, your transformation adds it only after 's'. How to tweak it to suit my needs better?

I also need to turn on disable-output-escaping="yes" for text element. It's for hyperlinks in the text. How can I do this, please?

Comment: @johnnym26: You are welcome. I just woke up in the morning, so you have been waiting for an answer for more than 6 hours -- sorry for the time difference. This solution was just to give you an example how to solve the problem. I don't know CZech, so I didn't try to do the "s/S/v/V/k/K/z/Z" thing, which wasn't explained in the question. As for DOE, I strongly recommend to avoid this as much as possible. See if serializing with the `htm`l method wouldn't produce the desired serialization.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made it very clear, but my interpretation of the question was that you wanted to use the second xsl:analyze-string to process the output of the first. You can do that by putting the result of the first one in a variable, but my recommendation would be put each xsl:analyze-string call in the body of a function, and compose them using function composition.

```
<xsl:function name="f:one" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="in".../>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="f:two" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="in".../>
</xsl:function>

... select="f:two(f:one(.))"...
```

However, in your case it's simpler because the first xsl:analyze-string can be done using a simple call on replace().